# Disk space Issue on Fast Search Server SharePoint 2010

Tags: 2010, fast-search

I am facing the disk space issue on Fast Search server. The below Location `E:\FASTSearch\data\sprel\worker\build_proc`.

It is having 202 GB of content which consists of files having a type as 0.

- what is the purpose of this files?
- should I go ahead with deleting this files from the build_proc folder to free up space?

Please share your thoughts.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**What is the purpose of these files within `SPRel` ?**

SPRel is a clickthrough log analysis engine that improves search results relevancy by analyzing the entries that users click on in search result sets.

**Should I go ahead with deleting this files from the build_proc folder to free up space?**

Yes, but you should first Stop first `FAST Search Server services` to can delete these files 
without issue.

Check also [MSDN Article regarding SPRel consuming more disk space](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/microsoft_search_bloggers/2015/02/10/sprel-consuming-more-disk-space-and-spreladmin-status-not-showing-as-ready/)